# Add class to clicked item and removed from all other, but if the same item clicked again then remove class from that as well, jQuery

Tags: jquery

my question has two part, first one is clear with me, I am having the problem with second part.

Here is my Code which I am trying..

```
$('.myDiv').click(function(e){
    $('.myDiv').next('.child').removeClass('test');
    $(this).next('.child').toggleClass('test');     
});
```

this code is doing the first part very well that adding the class to clicked div and removing from all other, but I need if I will click the same myDiv again then the class test need to be removed from that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to exclude currently clicked div i.e. `this` from `$('.myDiv')` matched elements using [`.not(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) method and then remove classes

```
$('.myDiv').click(function(e){
    $('.myDiv').not(this).next('.child').removeClass('test');
    $(this).next('.child').toggleClass('test');     
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution satpal, I have one more problem Can I ask you here in comments or ask a new question

Comment: @Atul, You can share your problem in comments also if I can then will surely help

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.myDiv', function(e){
    $('.myDiv').next('.child').removeClass('test');
    if($(this).next('.child').hasClass('test')){
      $(this).next('.child').removeClass('test');
    }else{
      $(this).next('.child').addClass('test');
    }   
});
```